# Why is the max() function returning an item that is smaller than another one in a list?

Tags: python, max

Here's the code in question:

```
my_list = ['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana']
print(max(my_list)
```

Why does it print 'oranges' instead of 'cherries'?

Comment: Oranges comes after cherries alphabetically.

Comment: Max doesn't return the longest string, it returns whichever comes the last lexicographically. max('aaaaa', 'b') returns 'b'.

Comment: You may as well ask why it doesn't return `'banana`, since that is last in the list.

Comment: There's no need to be rude about me not understanding how max() works. It seems reasonable enough from a newbie perspective to think it would return the longest string. I never assumed it meant to return the *last* string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are sorted lexicographically, relative to each other. `o` comes after `a`, `b`, and `c`. The length isn't a factor unless the strings are identical up to that point, in which case the shorter string is judged as 'less'. `max()`, then, produces the lexicographically greatest string (i.e. furthest back in the dictionary).

If you want to sort by length, you have to give the `max()` function a key (for example, the `len()` function):

```
>>> my_list = ['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana']
>>> print(max(my_list))
oranges
>>> print(max(my_list, key=len))
cherries
```

Answer (score 3):

The `max()` function returns the item with the highest value, or the item with the highest value in an iterable.

If the values are strings, an alphabetically comparison is done.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_max.asp